# Unable to run Debug APK in Real Device

Tags: react-native, apk

I have created the Debug APK in React native but while executing the APK in real device getting the following an error :

[image: Unable to load script]

I have used the following steps to create a Debug APK in react native:

1. `./gradlew clean`
2. `npx react-native bundle --dev true --platform android --entry-file index.js --bundle-output ./android/app/src/main/assets/index.android --assets-dest ./android/app/src/main/res/`
3. `./gradlew assembleDebug`

after using the above command I have generated the APK but while executing the APK getting an error.
I want the APK should run in the device.

Answer (score 0):

Use the command as following in sequence:

1. *npx react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res*
2. *cd android/*
3. *./gradlew assembleDebug*

Lastly make sure to uninstall the previous build from your device then copy the generated debug apk into your device to install it.